# How to run express server on Shared Hosting?

Tags: node.js, express, server, hosting

My shared hosting doesn't allow me customization. But, I anyhow installed `nodejs`. I also wrote an express server code inside `/var/www/test-server` directory.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

• But, I cannot access express server 
• I can't use port 80. 
• When I use some other ports like 8080, then I can see console output on Terminal as below:

```
example.work@example:/var/www/test-server$ node index.js 
Example app listening on port 8080
```

Now, my question is — 
"**Is it possible to access express server with or without port through browser?**" 
Like: `http://example.com/test-server`

Answer (score 0):

You must set up NGINX for the express server to be available on a Domain.
Alternatively, you can access the server at `http://ipofthemachine:port`
Make sure the port you are using is exposed if you have any firewall in place.

Comment: My server already has Apache running.